# Resources error when I add espresso-contrib

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-espresso

When I include espresso-contrib library to my gradle

> androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.1.1

I have no problems syncing but when I try to run a test I get the following errors in the build:

[image]

I can't go back to com.android.support as all my espresso dependencies are in androidX.
I think it may be due to appcompat dependency on espresso-contrib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by setting compileSdkVersion to 28.

Apparently you should do this if you migrate to AndroidX.